# Java - Cannot deserialize a json without double quotes using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a response coming from API in the following format

```
{"schema":[output_item, score],
"data":[[item1, 1], [item2, 2]]}
```

I am trying to serialize and deserialize this json using

```
 Class1 obj = getFromApiCall();
 ObjectMapper o = new ObjectMapper();
 map.put("first", o.writeAsString(obj)); // Map can only accept strings
 
 String res = map.get("first");
 Object obj2 = o.readValue(res, Class1)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Unexpected character ('o' (code 111)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@68bba850; line: 1, column: 13]
```

How do I make sure that I can serialize and deserialize the objet coming from API call?

Comment: Why are you not using a good library like retrofit? Gsonconverter will help you easily deserialize to pojo

Comment: What kind of API is this? That's no valid JSON data.

Comment: @BenjaminM rest api and internal, cannot change it